# How an iPhone devices talk to embedded bluetooth devices

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth

I am trying to develop an app that is used to communicate with another embedded device. But, i have no idea about how to make it possible. From blogs, i found that iPhone will not interact with other devices. Is there any Bluetooth chip that helps to connect with iPhone. Also, how we can communicate between this two devices.

Comment: Are you trying to transfer data from one ios device to other ios device?

Comment: Yes between iPhone and embedded device using bluetooth, Now i developed the embedded device, but how can i read its data from iPhone using bluetooth.

Comment: embedded device is ios device or any other ?

Comment: Its another device, not iOS.

Comment: Ok..then sorry..no idea

Comment: Hello @Jio did you get the solution for this? I have the same requirement as yours.

Comment: @Rohan: You can communicate with BLE device using corebluetooth framework. If you want to communicate with Bluetooth classic device, you need MFi certification